# How can I fade out an AVAudioPlayer on a background thread?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, avaudioplayer, nsthread

I have an audio file which needs to fade out while the user is scrolling a UIScrollView. However, any `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method is blocked until the user has stopped scrolling. So I have tried to create some code to perform a fadeout on another thread:

```
- (void)fadeOut
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fadeOutInBackground:) toTarget:self withObject:self.audioPlayer];
}

- (void)fadeOutInBackground:(AVAudioPlayer *)aPlayer
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *myPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self performSelector:@selector(fadeVolumeDown:) withObject:aPlayer afterDelay:0.1]; 
    [myPool release];
}

- (void)fadeVolumeDown:(AVAudioPlayer *)aPlayer
{
    aPlayer.volume = aPlayer.volume - 0.1;
    if (aPlayer.volume < 0.1) {
        [aPlayer stop];         
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(fadeVolumeDown:) withObject:aPlayer afterDelay:0.1];  
    }
}
```

It gets as far as the performSelector, but no further because I guess it's trying to perform on a thread it has no access to. I can't even change it for `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` because there is no delay option.

Any ideas? Why have they made it so hard to just fade out a sound? *moan*

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I resolved a similar issue by scheduling the selector in a different run loop mode than the default one.  This way it is not interfering with the scrolling events.  Using the `NSRunLoopCommonModes` worked for me:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fadeVolumeDown:) 
           withObject:aPlayer
           afterDelay:0.1 
              inModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject: NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer above

```
   while (theAudio.volume > 0.000000)
        [self fadeVolumeDown];

- (void) fadeVolumeDown{
    theAudio.volume -=0.01;
}
```